# How to populate a variable based on the choice of another variable in Grafana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, grafana

I have a dashboard which uses AWS Cloudwatch as datasource.
I have a variable `Region` which gives me regions of AWS i.e. `us-east-1, us-west-2` etc.
I want to create another variable called `RegionCode` which populates itself based on the selection of `Region` variable.

For example: If I select `us-east-1` from `Region` dropdown, `RegionCode` variable gets populated with `USE1` and if I select `us-west-2`, it gets populated with `USW2`. I have been browsing around all over the web to look for a way but can't figure it out.

Please help.

Comment: where will you the regioncodes from? is it present in some database?

Comment: no I just want to hardcode it

Comment: Hmm.. That may not be possible.